# Passing arguments in functions + return - why doesn't this work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with a Palindrome-detector that is built using for-loops (this was a requirement for the course I am attending).

I am almost fully done with it but I am having trouble returning an argument and using it in the final function. The code looks like this:

```
  #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def main(): 
    intro()
    text = (input("Inser text here: "))
    ordnaText(text)
    testPalindrom(ordnaText(text))
    showResult(testPalindrom)


def intro():
    print ("Hej! Detta är ett program som testar ifall en text är ett palindrom eller inte.")

def ordnaText (text):
    nytext = ("")
    fixedText = text.lower()
    for i in fixedText:
        if i.isalnum():
            nytext = (nytext + i)
    return nytext

def testPalindrome(nytext):
    palindrome = True
    for i in range (0, len(nytext)):
        if (nytext[i]) != (nytext[len(nytext)-i-1]):
            palindrome = False
    return palindrome

def showResult(palindrome):
    if palindrome == True:
        print ("Yes, this is a palindrome")
    else:
        print ("No, this is not a palindrome.)
main()
```

Everything works except the final part: if I put in "lol" which is a palindrome it says that it's false. "palindrome" somehow doesn't return correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

For short strings, to test for palindromes just compare it against the reverse:

```
def testPalindrome(nytext):
    return nytext == nytext[::-1]
```

Your version of `testPalindrome` works fine, but your method itself calls `testPalindrom(ordnaText(text))` (no `e` at the end), so perhaps you have another definition of the function?

```
>>> def testPalindrome(nytext):
...     palindrome = True
...     for i in range (0, len(nytext)):
...         if (nytext[i]) != (nytext[len(nytext)-i-1]):
...             palindrome = False
...     return palindrome
... 
>>> testPalindrome('lol')
True
```

You don't actually pass the *result* of the function to `showResult`; you pass the *function* instead. Use a variable:

```
result = testPalindrome(ordnaText(text))
showResult(result)
```

You can simplify this down a little:

```
def testPalindrome(nytext):
    for i in range (0, len(nytext)):
        if (nytext[i]) != (nytext[len(nytext)-i-1]):
            return False
    return True
```

You can exit early when you find the first non-matching character.

You don't need to test for `== True` in if statements, just do:

```
def showResult(palindrome):
    if palindrome:
        print ("Yes, this is a palindrome")
    else:
        print ("No, this is not a palindrome.)
```

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: Please just answer the question and nothing else. The rest of the code works to my liking.

Comment: All your points are valid observations, but none answer the question. -1

Comment: My +1 as the task is apparently a homework. Then the best help is to point to the issues.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem mainly lies in your main function:

```
ordnaText(text)
```

This calls the `ordnaText` function with the entered text as its parameter; and then it throws the result away.

```
testPalindrom(ordnaText(text))
```

Now this calls the `testPalindrom` function with the result from the `ordnaText` method; and then again it throws the result away. As you have already called the `ordnaText` method, it is also a good idea to store the result before, so you can just pass its result.

```
showResult(testPalindrom)
```

And finally, you call the `showResult` function with the *function* as a parameter. At this point, there is nothing that refers to the entered text, you just pass the function itself. So what you want to do here is pass the result of the `testPalindrom` function here:

```
text = input("Inser text here: ")
text = ordnaText(text)
testResult = testPalindrom(text)
showResult(testResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (slightly cleaner code, same logic) :

```
def testPalindrome(str) :
    for i in range(int(len(str)/2)) :
        if str[i] != str[len(str)-i-1] :
             return False

    return True
```

Also, you arent doing anything with the result returned :

```
    testPalindrom(ordnaText(text)) #This returns the result, but there is no variable that accepts it


    showResult(testPalindrom)
```

You could do :

```
showResult(testPalindrom(ordnaText(text))) #This will print the returned result
```

Or :

```
    result = testPalindrom(ordnaText(text))

    showResult(result)
```

Advice : You can make this code much much shorter and tidier.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the result of testPalindrom to showResult

By doing

```
ordnaText(text)
testPalindrom(ordnaText(text))
showResult(testPalindrom)
```

you pass the function itself to showResult (which is an object) which is not equal to True

so you should do instead of this three lines

```
showResult(testPalindrom(ordnaText(text)))
```

Comment: A function object is true in that `bool` coerces it into `True`. It is not equal to `True`, which is what the code checks.